# Nested LinkedList in c

Tags: c

```
struct songs
{
    char* name[MAX];
    double length;
    struct songs *next;
};
typedef struct songs songs;

struct albums
{
    char* title[MAX];
    int year;
    char* singerName[MAX];
    songs songs;
    struct albums *next;
};

struct albums *head = NULL;
struct albums *curr = NULL;
struct songs *bas=NULL;
struct songs *current=NULL;
```

I defined structures.Second part holds the list of all albums. First part holds list of songs.And albums have songs.

```
void add(char albumTitle[],char singerName[], int releaseYear )
{
    struct albums *temp;
    temp=(struct albums *)malloc(sizeof(struct albums));
    strcpy( temp->title, albumTitle );
    temp->year=releaseYear;
    strcpy( temp->singerName, singerName );
    if (head== NULL)
    {
    curr=head=temp;
    head->next=NULL;
    curr->next=NULL;
    }
     else
    {
     curr->next=temp;
     curr=temp;
    }

    printf("Done\n");
}
```

This part is using to add an album.And finally,

```
void addSong(char albumTitle[],char songName[], double songLength )
{
    struct albums *temp;
    temp=(struct albums *)malloc(sizeof(struct albums));
    temp=head;

    struct songs *tempsong;
    tempsong=(struct songs *)malloc(sizeof(struct songs));
    tempsong=bas=current;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(!(strcmp(temp->title, albumTitle)))
        {
            bas=temp->songs;                
            strcpy(tempsong->name,songName);
            tempsong->length=songLength;
                if (bas== NULL)
                {
                bas=tempsong;
                bas->next=NULL;
                current->next=NULL;
                }
                 else
                {
                 current->next=tempsong;
                 current=tempsong;
                }
            break;    
        }
        else
        {
            temp= temp->next;
        }
    }

}
```

This part need to add a song for albums.My problem is in this part.How can I add songs in big linkedlist?
Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Just to let you know, `char* name[MAX]` is an array of `MAX` strings, not a string of length `MAX`.

Comment: Okey @BrendanLong.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the very same technique you used for adding albums. There's no difference. Use `gdb` or any other debugger to step through the code (`break main`, `run`, `next` and `step` commands in gdb), print out the state of your data (`print` in gdb) and see what's wrong.

See: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/

Comment: Yes you are right. I think as you.And I wrote this code.But When I compiled , It didn't work.

Comment: @Semih You would have to be more specific about what exactly didn't work.

Comment: @Semih You should show us the code that didn't work, with the error message.

Comment: Last part that didn't work. And I have no error message. Program is finished automatically

Comment: @Semih Time to learn using a debugger. I'm ok with GDB's CLI interface but you can use just anything that suits you.